# Não redireciona para Página de Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autenticação, web.config

Para fazer a autenticação no meu sistema estou usando o atributo `[Authorize]` coloquei esse código abaixo no ***Web.Config*** para quando ocorrer o *Código 401* que é relacionado a não autenticação ele redireciona-se para a minha página de login.

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.html" mode="RemoteOnly">
<error statusCode="401" redirect="Login/Login"/>
```

Porém não está redirecionando e nem gerando erro.

Comment: Na verdade se a página devolve um 401, já deveria redirecionar sem precisar disso. Você está usando ASP.NET Identity?

Comment: Obrigado pela Sugestão, usei a maneira que abaixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira correta de realizar esse redirecionamento para a View de login é através da tag `authentication` no seu arquivo `Web.config`. Segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="/SignIn" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Note que você deve obrigatoriamente definir o atributo `mode` como `Forms` e logo em seguida no atributo `loginUrl` da tag `forms` você especifica a URL da sua View de login.